# Ruby on Rails: How to set which development environment an app runs in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, mongrel, fedora

I'm relatively new to Ruby on Rails and occasionally I find this convention-over-configuration stuff a little confusing as a lot of things seemed to be hidden from the developer, as in this case.

I'm using rails 2.3.8 and when I run my app locally through NetBeans 6.9/Mongrel on my system it runs using the development environment parameters.. when I deploy it to a Fedora box and run it there in Apache HTTPD it automatically runs using the production environment parameters.

How does my app know which environment to use? I haven't changed anything in my app to set the environment.. both versions locally and on my Fedora box are identical. I can't find anywhere in the code where it is setting the environment.. so how is this working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In httpd.conf file, write the following in VirtualHost:-

> ## Specify Rails Environment here,
>      default value is "production"
>      RailsEnv development

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

The primary way to specify rails mode is `RAILS_ENV` environment variable (I assume `development` is default, when nothing is specified). You can check its value in bash, `echo $RAILS_ENV`.
You can also modify `ENV['RAILS_ENV']` in your config file to change the mode:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'production'
```

**edit**
I've never used rails with apache, but I think passenger mod can also specify this variable somewhere, checking apache configs might help.