# How practical is it to run a Rails server with Apache or Nginx even in development mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Since WEBrick or Mongrel might be limited to not having `keep-alive` etc, can't Apache or Nginx be used with Rails even in development mode?

For example, running Apache there always, and attach Rails to it, so that starting Rails meaning starting the Rails part, and no webserver such as WEBrick or Mongrel need to be started.  Is that feasible?  On some Mac, even Apache is running all the time when the system Settings has the "Web sharing" selected.

Comment: sure it can, just don't set any environment, it will be development by default

Comment: but it will be WEBrick or mongrel

Comment: any server try http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Standalone.html it should do the job

Answer (score 2):

You can use Apache or nginx or any server of your choice for any environment you wish to run. But you can't just start it with `rails server`.

As described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450843/ruby-on-rails-how-to-set-which-development-environment-an-app-runs-in/4450983#4450983), you just need to set the right option in your `httpd.conf`, in the section that serves your rails:

> ```
> ## Specify Rails Environment here, default value is "production"
> RailsEnv development
> ```